# how to know if Caffe2 has been successfully installed or not in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, caffe2

I am trying install caffe2 as instructed, on https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=ubuntu&configuration=compile, but when I try to run the command

```
python -c 'from caffe2.python import core' 2>/dev/null && echo "Success" || echo "Failure"
```

it echo failure.
further when I run next command

```
python -m caffe2.python.operator_test.relu_op_test
```

It gives output as -
`Error while finding module specification for 'caffe2.python.operator_test.relu_op_test' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'caffe2.python')`

While I have successfully run the other commands, Can anyone please point out the mistake/s I am committing.
How do I know if i have successfully installed caffe2 ?(other than above command)

Comment: Did the compilation work without any errors?

Comment: Actually are few commands on the link (In question) for installing caffe2, I tried installing using them but last two commands are not giving required results, all the commands before that were successful.

Comment: Can you check that your build directory is in `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: ... or execute that command from the build folder. There must be some errors in the previous commands. Try `make clean`, rebuild, and post the end of the output from the `sudo make install` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [post](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron/blob/master/INSTALL.md):

```
# To check if Caffe2 build was successful
python -c 'from caffe2.python import core' 2>/dev/null && echo "Success" || echo "Failure"

# To check if Caffe2 GPU build was successful
# This must print a number > 0 in order to use Detectron
python -c 'from caffe2.python import workspace; print(workspace.NumCudaDevices())'
```